# VB.NET Can we Clone Columns from Datagridview to DataTable

Tags: vb.net

I created Columns with header and data Property information in Datagridview, Is it possible to clone that to DataTable. I used

```
Dim dt2 As DataTable = DataGridView2.DataSource.clone
```

But I get error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: You can build a DataTable, add Columns, define the type of data these Columns contain, use the DataTable as the DataSource of your DGV and add data to it. You DataTable is filled with the new data. Otherwise, you have to iterate the DGV's Rows collection, read the data casting to the correct type and add Rows to an empty DataTable. If you defined the Columns in the designer and you added new data in the UI, your DGV has no DataSource, just values in its Cells.

Comment: A `DataGridView` does magically have a data source unless you set one. What you should be doing is creating the `DataTable` first and binding that to the grid. That can generate the columns for you or you can bind to existing columns. You can build the `DataTable` schema yourself or it can be generated automatically by calling `Fill` or `FillSchema` on a data adapter.

Comment: @jimi, thats the ideal way to do it, but I thought if I could take a shortcut :) I guess I have to do it right way than shortcut

Comment: @jmcilhinney Fill or Fill Schema Let me try that, or may be will go through creating Datatable first. Thanks for the help

Comment: What I described is the *shortcut* :) You avoid reversing the data and data type conversion shenanigans altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set datatable to DataGridView.DataSource you can:
example:

```
        Dim MyDataTableSource As New DataTable
    MyDataTableSource.Columns.Add("Mycolumn1")
    MyDataTableSource.Columns.Add("Mycolumn2")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = MyDataTableSource

    Dim MyDataTable As New DataTable
    MyDataTable = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).Clone
    MyDataTable.Clear()
```

Comment: hmm, Let me try and report back, Thanks for help